# C: How to open a file using the parameter to main argv?

Tags: c, file, argv

I've been trying to open a file using the char** argv parameter. But unfortunately, I stumped upon a problem reading the path to the file when I pass it in this format: program.exe Function SourceFile DestFile.

I'm using notepad++ to write the code and GCC to compile and pass the arguments to the function

UPDATE: I fixed the code, should be working right now...

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

void textCopy(FILE* sourceFile, FILE* destinationFile);
void binaryCopy(FILE* sourceFile, FILE* destinationFile);

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    printf(argv[2]);
    if ((strcmp(argv[1], "textCopy") != 0 && strcmp(argv[1], "binaryCopy") != 0))
    {
        printf("Error: Function Doesn't Exist");
        return 1;
    }
    FILE* sourceFile = fopen(argv[2], "r");
    if (sourceFile == NULL)
    {
        printf("Error: Source File Doesn't Exist");
        return 1;
    }
    FILE* destinationFile = fopen(argv[3], "w");
    if (destinationFile == NULL)
    {
        printf("Error: Destination File Doesn't Exist");
    }
    if (strcmp(argv[1], "textCopy") == 0)
    {
        textCopy(sourceFile, destinationFile);
    }
    else
    {
        binaryCopy(sourceFile, destinationFile);
    }
    getchar();
    return 0;
}

void textCopy(FILE* sourceFile, FILE* destinationFile)
{
    char letter = 0;
    while (letter != EOF)
    {
        letter = fgetc(sourceFile);
        fputc(letter, destinationFile);
    }
}

void binaryCopy(FILE* sourceFile, FILE* destinationFile)
{
    printf("Ignore");
}
```

I searched for solutions in the internet but nothing seemed to work out, when i read argv[2] i only get the C:\ part from the path and not the whole path...

Thanks!

Comment: it isn't compiling because the indetation is wrong.. opps

Comment: No it should not have any more errors

Comment: i meant to write Now* ... I'll remember that for the next time. thanks.

Comment: I think you also should explain what environment you are using to write, compile and run the code. It seems to be relevant for this question. Please study [ask] and create a question where you clearly state the expected and actual behavior.

Comment: Interesting how much a simple typo can change things. :)

Comment: indeed xD i added the stuff you asked me to add. *now* it should be alright

Comment: Never use `printf(argv[1])`. What you mean is either `fputs(argv[1], stdout);`, `printf("%s", argv[1]);` or perhaps even `puts(argv[1]);`

Comment: oh lol... I didn't notice that xD I've been using python for the past month and now I'm using C like python ;-;

Comment: If you want to know *why not*, try a path like `"C:\100 % should not work"` ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try something in the spirit of:

```
program.exe textCopy "C:\path to\the source file\my source file.ext" "C:\path to\the destination file\my destination file.ext"
```

It's the double quotes around the file path in the command line you're missing.

Comment: Wow your actually correct. is there any way to avoid using quotation around the paths?

Comment: Yes. If you avoid white space in the full file path and name, you can avoid using quotation. You could replace the white spaces with dash marks or underscores for example.